# Mono Winforms Problem

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mono

Hey , does anyone know why a winform application in windows,
reaches via the ending program flow , to the point :

this.close (of the main form) ,

closes the application normaly in windows , 
but in Mono the windows get stucked... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `Application.Exit()` instead. If you really want the `Close` event to fire, call `Application.Exit()` after you call `Close`.